# how to convert already converted numeric field to date type?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I need to convert the Prelim Date field below to date type.

```
select
       [Initial Rated Date/Time],
       floor(convert(numeric(10,2),[Initial Rated Date/Time])-.08333333) as 'Prelim Date'
from [AX2cTest].[dbo].[AAATRANSPORTTABLE_V]
```

sample data:

```
Initial Rated Date/Time   Prelim Date
2020-08-03 02:01:00.000     44046
2020-08-03 01:59:00.000     44045
```

I need this:

```
Initial Rated Date/Time    Prelim Date
2020-08-03 02:01:00.000     2020-08-03
2020-08-03 01:59:00.000     2020-08-02
```

I tried these two queries, but received the below errors:

```
select
       [Initial Rated Date/Time],
       convert(date,floor(convert(numeric(10,2),[Initial Rated Date/Time])-.08333333)) as 'Prelim 
       Date'
from [AX2cTest].[dbo].[AAATRANSPORTTABLE_V]
```

error: Explicit conversion from data type numeric to date is not allowed.

```
with Prelim_Rpt_Date_CTE (Prelim_Rpt_Date)  as (select
       floor(convert(numeric(10,2),[Initial Rated Date/Time])-.08333333)
       from [AX2cTest].[dbo].[AAATRANSPORTTABLE_V])

select convert(date,Prelim_Rpt_Date)
from Prelim_Rpt_Date_CTE;
```

error: Explicit conversion from data type numeric to date is not allowed.

How can I work around this error?

Comment: 0.08333333 <> "12 hours".

Comment: To "subtract a fraction of 12 hours" - how about `DATEADD(MINUTE, -<that many minutes>`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You seem to want something like this:

```
select convert(date, dateadd(hour, -2, [Initial Rated Date/Time]))
```

I'm not sure why you want to get numerics and integers and floats involved in what looks like a simple day computation.